# Class Template member doesn't exist error

Tags: c++, templates

I'm just learning about templates and I'm running into an error between my class template and calling a member function once I'm trying to use that template.

Class Template

```
template<class T> class MyVector{
    private:
       int dataMembers;
    public:
        template<class T>
        void MyVector<T>::push_back(){//body of the function}
};
```

Driver

```
int main()
{ 
     MyVector<Account*> bankAccounts;
     bankAccounts.push_back(//dynamic object);
     //error: class MyVector<Account*> has no member "push_back"
     //... 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will help if you explicitly state your question.

Comment: Don't provide the inner template statement.

Comment: When I am calling the push_back function on my new vector called bankAccounts (which contains pointers to dynamic objects) i am getting the red squiggly of death under push_back and the error is the one listed above in the commented error. My boiler plate for the template must be wrong in my ,cpp , but I don't know how.

Comment: @Neil Kirk: ty :) that did it. my prof gave met that; must only be for non-member functions, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can either declare and define template function inside class like this:

```
template<class T>
class MyVector {
    private:
       int dataMembers;
    public:
        void push_back( T arg ) {
            //some code
        }
};
```

Or define the body outside:

```
template<class T>
class MyVector {
    private:
       int dataMembers;
    public:
        void push_back( T arg );
};

template<class T>
void MyVector<T>::push_back( T arg ) {
    //some code
}
```